# How to find wrong definition IN JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

Do you know how to find wrong definition in JOIN  ... ON?
During two days I wrote wrong code, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a JOIN 
     table2 b
     ON a.Id = a.Id
```

I can not be sure that this bug is not also in other functions or procedures or views... I have many objects and I would like find this bugs if it exists.
Is there some easy way how to find it, or do I have to write some utility?

Comment: SO you don't know how many places you have used this code?

Comment: There is no way to check these type instances, you have to manually check & confirm all things (on clause with exact condition based business logic).

Comment: Is this SQL Server? You could check the `syscomments` table.

Comment: You don't tell us what your development environment is, so we can't tell you how to find queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the [syscomments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscomments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table for these instances:

```
select distinct object_name(id)
    from sys.syscomments
    where text like '%a.Id = a.Id%'
```

Comment: This can not be use because I do not know exactly syntax a.Id = a.Id
In join, procedures, functions, views are differents tables and joins and I would like to find "wrong" syntax only.
It have to be dynamic query...... left side equals right side